# How to restrict the search fields for a specific post type

Tags: wp-query

How can I restrict the search for a specific post type?  I am using the following code in functions.php:

```
function searchfilter($query) { 
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ){return;}

    if( $query->is_main_query()  ) {
       $query->set( 'post_type', ['property']);
     }   
     return $query;
 }   
add_filter('pre_get_posts','searchfilter');
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, thanks

```
function my_search_pre_get_posts($query)
{

    if($query->query_vars['s'] != '' && is_search())
    {

        if(absint($query->query_vars['s']))
        {
            $query->set('p', $query->query_vars['s']);
            $query->set('post_type', ['property']);
            // Reset the search value
            $query->set('s', '');
        }
    }
}

// Filter the search page
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'my_search_pre_get_posts');
```

A very good learning of WordPress functionality.